# Getting temperature dependence for a beta multiplier circuit

Tags: mosfet, analog, design, cmos, calculus

I am currently working on designing a beta multiplier voltage reference, and came across [this paper](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/document?repid=rep1&type=pdf&doi=8fa2d8e22d52bd31c948aa19220eaac8b2427289#:%7E:text=Beta%2DMultiplier%20Voltage%20Reference&text=Experimental%20results%20from%20a%202,a%20supply%20sensitivity%20under%2050mVN).

I am slightly confused as to how they ended up with equation (6) after taking the derivative of (5) with respect to temperature.

It would be appreciated if someone could show how to do it and provide an intuitive understanding of how to approach these sorts of derivatives, specifically for application purposes as in the case below.

---

Solving for \$I\$ and \$V_{REF}\$ using the three equations yields
$$
I=\frac{2}{R^2\,\beta_1}
{\left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{K}} \right)}^2 
\tag{4}
$$
and
$$
V_{REF} = V_{GS1} = \frac{2}{R\,\beta_1}
\left(1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{K}} \right) + V_{THN}.
\tag{5}
$$
The temperature coefficient of the voltage reference is given by
$$
\frac{{\rm d}V_{REF}}{{\rm d}T} = 
\frac{{\rm d}V_{THN}}{{\rm d}T} - \frac{2}{R\,\beta_1}
\left( 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{K}} \right)
\left(
  \frac{1}{R} \frac{{\rm d}R}{{\rm d}T} +
  \frac{1}{KP(T)} \frac{{\rm d}KP(T)}{{\rm d}T}
\right)
\tag{6}
$$

---

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to ignore the \$V_{_\text{THN}}\$ term and focus on the remaining term, which is a product of two functions.

If you have the product of two functions, call them \$P\$ and \$Q\$, so that \$F=Q\cdot P\$, then the product rule would have:

$$\begin{align*}
\text{d} F&= P\cdot\text{d} Q+Q\cdot\text{d} P
\\\\
&= \frac{Q}{Q}\cdot P\cdot\text{d} Q+\frac{P}{P}\cdot Q\cdot\text{d} P
\\\\
&= Q\cdot P\cdot\frac{\text{d} Q}{Q}+P\cdot Q\cdot\frac{\text{d} P}{P}
\\\\
&= Q\cdot P\cdot\left[\frac{\text{d} Q}{Q}+\frac{\text{d} P}{P}\right]\tag{1}\label{eq:1}
\end{align*}$$

The way to read the above Eq. \ref{eq:1} is to think: *"The differential change in the product of \$Q\$ and \$P\$ is that same product times the sum of the %-change in \$Q\$ plus the %-change in \$P\$."*

*(Note that I've not yet actually taken the derivative with respect to any other infinitesimal. In fact, I don't yet even know what \$P\$ and \$Q\$ are functions of. And I don't care. This is how I prefer to perform calculus. I don't know anything about \$P\$ or \$Q\$ except that they may yet become functions of something. Yet I have already been able to say something useful about the differential of their product!)*

In your specific case:

\$P\$ is a function of \$K\$, so write: \$P_{_\text{K}}=1-\frac1{\sqrt{K}}\$.

\$Q\$ is a function of \$R\$, so write: \$Q_{_\text{R}}=\frac2{\beta_1\,R}\$.

$$\begin{align*}\require{cancel}
\text{d} F&= Q\cdot P\cdot\left[\frac{\text{d} Q}{Q}+\frac{\text{d} P}{P}\right]
\\\\
\frac{\text{d} F}{\text{d}\,T}&= Q_{_\text{R}}\cdot P_{_\text{K}}\cdot\left[\frac{\frac{\text{d}\, Q_{_\text{R}}}{\text{d}R}}{Q_{_\text{R}}}\cdot\frac{\text{d}\,R}{\text{d}T}+\frac{\frac{\text{d}\, P_{_\text{K}}}{\cancel{\text{d}K}}}{P_{_\text{K}}}\cdot\frac{\cancel{\text{d}\,K}}{\text{d}T}\right]
\\\\
&\quad\quad\text{substituting, } \frac{\frac{\text{d}\, Q_{_\text{R}}}{\text{d}R}}{Q_{_\text{R}}}=-\frac1{R}
\\\\
&= Q_{_\text{R}}\cdot P_{_\text{K}}\cdot\left[\frac{-\text{d}\,R}{R}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{d}T}+\frac{\text{d}\, P_{_\text{K}}}{P_{_\text{K}}}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{d}T}\right]\tag{2}\label{eq:2}
\\\\
&= Q_{_\text{R}}\cdot P_{_\text{K}}\cdot\left[\frac{-\text{d}\,R}{R}+\frac{\text{d}\, P_{_\text{K}}}{P_{_\text{K}}}\right]\cdot\frac{1}{\text{d}T}\tag{3}\label{eq:3}
\\\\
&\quad\quad\text{or also,}\\\\
\frac{\text{d} F}{F}&=\frac{\text{d}\, P_{_\text{K}}}{P_{_\text{K}}}-\frac{\text{d}\,R}{R}\tag{4}\label{eq:4}
\end{align*}$$

That's what I come up with just applying math and not attempting to read the paper with understanding.

Take note that Eq. \$\ref{eq:2}\$ casts, yet again, things in terms of %-change in \$R\$ and %-change in \$P_{_\text{K}}\$. Looking at things as %-change helps focus on a *sensitivity* viewpoint, which is a very powerful way to consider issues at hand. To ask, "*How sensitive is the output to a %-change in input \$x\$ or a %-change in input \$y\$?"*, is quite powerful!

Compare Eq. \$\ref{eq:2}\$ with equation 7 in your document, perhaps. I suspect their **KP(T)** is \$P_{_\text{K}}\$, above, knowing that **K** is a function of **T**. *(Eq. \$\ref{eq:3}\$ is just another way of writing it.)*

I think Eq. \$\ref{eq:4}\$ may also be important to understand. It says how a %-change in \$V_{_\text{REF}}\$ depends on %-changes elsewhere. And it suggests a way to consider how one may attempt to zero-out, or at least minimize the worst case of, any variation in \$V_{_\text{REF}}\$ by balancing two terms. But it isn't covered in your document. So I'll leave it, for now.